# How to get Orders with some criteria via PHP CURL

Tags: php, curl, bigcommerce

I want to get all orders using the **Bigcommerce PHP** library with following criteria.

**- Order status = 2 (Shipped)**

**- Order created before 2 days**

I am trying to get orders with CURL call in PHP

When i am passing just

```
$api_url = 'https://www.myapiurl.com/api/v2/orders.json?status_id=2';
```

It returning all shipped orders but when i am trying to pass date filter it not getting desired result

```
$api_url = 'https://www.myapiurl.com/api/v2/orders.json?status_id=2&min_date_created=2015-08-30';
```

$api_url = 'https://www.myapiurl.com/api/v2/orders.json?status_id=2&min_date_created=2015-08-30';

How would I do that?

Comment: It's likely that `min_date_created` is not the right parameter. Have you checked the documentation on the `orders` resource?

Comment: yes checked
https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/stores/v2/orders

Comment: Looks liek the date should be in this format: Thu, 15 Nov 2012 21:43:32 +0000

Comment: try using this format ** Wed, 14 Nov 2012 19:26:23 +0000 **

Comment: It gives following response:

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [status] => 400
            [message] => The field 'min_date_created' is invalid.
            [details] => Array
                (
                    [invalid_reason] => The provided value '"Thu, 15 Nov 2012 21:43:32  0000"' is not a valid RFC-2822 or ISO-8601 date.
                )

        )

)

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this format at a store and work for me(I'm using the php api version 3 from bigommerce).

```
https://store-xxxxxxx.mybigcommerce.com/api/v2/orders?status_id=1&min_date_created=2015-03-04
```

response:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 25
            [customer_id] => 0
            [date_created] => Wed, 04 Mar 2015 17:36:34 +0000
            [date_modified] => Wed, 04 Mar 2015 17:36:34 +0000
            [date_shipped] => 
            [status_id] => 1
            [status] => Pending
            [subtotal_ex_tax] => 90.0000
            [subtotal_inc_tax] => 90.0000
            [subtotal_tax] => 0.0000
            [base_shipping_cost] => 0.0000
            [shipping_cost_ex_tax] => 0.0000
            [shipping_cost_inc_tax] => 0.0000
            [shipping_cost_tax] => 0.0000
            [shipping_cost_tax_class_id] => 0
            [base_handling_cost] => 0.0000
            [handling_cost_ex_tax] => 0.0000
            [handling_cost_inc_tax] => 0.0000
            [handling_cost_tax] => 0.0000
            [handling_cost_tax_class_id] => 0
            [base_wrapping_cost] => 0.0000
            [wrapping_cost_ex_tax] => 0.0000
            [wrapping_cost_inc_tax] => 0.0000
            [wrapping_cost_tax] => 0.0000
            [wrapping_cost_tax_class_id] => 0
            [total_ex_tax] => 80.0000
            [total_inc_tax] => 80.0000
            [total_tax] => 0.0000
            [items_total] => 1
            [items_shipped] => 0
            [payment_method] => Manual
            [payment_provider_id] => 
            [payment_status] => 
            [refunded_amount] => 0.0000
            [order_is_digital] => 
            [store_credit_amount] => 0.0000
            [gift_certificate_amount] => 0.0000
            [ip_address] => 
            [geoip_country] => 
            [geoip_country_iso2] => 
            [currency_id] => 1
            [currency_code] => USD
            [currency_exchange_rate] => 1.0000000000
            [default_currency_id] => 1
            [default_currency_code] => USD
            ......
            ....
            ..
            .
```